# How can I get the number of cells used in a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to know how close I am to the [limit of 2 million cells](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en) with a spreadsheet.

How can I find the information about how man cells I am using in a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Answer (score 8):

## Formula

```
=ROWS(A:A)*COLUMNS(1:1)
```

If you have more that one sheet, repeat the above pattern for each one as arguments of `SUM` or use the `+` operator

```
=SUM(ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)*COLUMNS(Sheet1!1:1),
     ROWS(Sheet2!A:A)*COLUMNS(Sheet2!1:1)
)
```

## Explanation

When used with open-ended references like A:A and 1:1, ROWS and COLUMNS returns the number of actual rows and columns.

An alternative is to use Google Apps Script. Below is a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

```
/**
 * Count the number of cells of the active spreadsheet
 *
 * @param {A1} input Used to force recalculation.
 * @customfuncion
 */
function cellsCount(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var cells = 0;
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    cells = cells + sheet.getMaxRows() * sheet.getMaxColumns();
  });
  return cells;
}
```

The argument is optional. It's recommended to include a cell that changes frequently but it should not contain a non-deterministic function like NOW(),  RAND(), etc.